# Actual data and presentation data is different in this React app

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

Am I missing something while rendering in React?

Data saved in the database is:

```
actual data
is
this
```

After rendering with React, data turns out like this:

```
actual data is this
```

I checked all data points, from the form to sending with Ajax and adding in database. The data is the same as it is being sent. And there isn't any such CSS content with the rule `display:inline`.

Comment: What is the html you’re using to display the data on the front end?

Comment: I don't know react well enough to be confident to answer this question properly. However, I can tell you that html doesn't display line breaks. Maybe you just need a `string.replace("\n", "<br>");`?

Comment: ```str.replace("\n","<br/>");``` does not work with react well. the below posted solution is perfect for work.Thank You for Help #HappyCoding

Comment: @oktupol if you want to avoid HTML in a string from being escaped, you have to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) (and be really sure of what you're doing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newlines (`'\n'`) in a given string do not result in line breaks in the rendered HTMl. You can add `<br/>` tags at the end of the lines, or wrap them in `<p>` tags:

**App.jsx**

```jsx
const React = require('react');
const reactDOM = require('react-dom');

function App(props) {
  const breaks = props.string2.split('\n').map((line) => <span>{line}<br /></span>);
  const paragraphs = props.string3.split('\n').map((line) => <p>{line}</p>);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {props.string1}
      </div>
      <div>
        {breaks}
      </div>
      <div>
        {paragraphs}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const string1 = 'will\n all\n be\n one\n line';
const string2 = 'will\n be\n on\n different\n lines\n with\n breaks';
const string3 = 'will\n be\n on\n different\n lines\n with\n paragraphs';

reactDOM.render(<App string1={string1} string2={string2} string3={string3} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This will render:

```
will all be one line
will
be
on
different
lines
with
breaks
will

be

on

different

lines

with

paragraphs
```

Comment: This one Really Worked. :) Thank You for Help @Kellen

Comment: @RahulShahare that's great to hear! If you mark the answer as accepted then others can be sure it's correct as well :)

Comment: sorry for accepting late. i am new to here and didnt knew abt this accept mark, but now i do. #HappyCoding @kellen

Comment: @RahulShahare No worries! Happy coding to you as well